# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Raw'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC3 , I kept my javascript file as an external , then it is showing the error as "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Raw'.

But if embed the Javascript file in xxx.cshtml, then it is not showing the error?

Below line it is throwing an error

var userItemName =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["ItemName"]));

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: The name of method or property may be 'row'. javascript is case-sensitive, so 'Row' and 'row' are not identical.

Comment: @madhu :  there is no problem in the line posted. please give some more information.

Comment: You can't put razor code in an external js file. Razor is parsed on the server when the view is rendered - it knows nothing about anything in an external js file, so you need to keep this line in the `cshtml` file (and pass the value to a function in the external file if necessary)

Comment: @Stephen : But due to some security problem, I need to put this code in a seperate Java script file.. Can you suggest any technique to pass the value in javascript to do some decoding

Comment: In the external file, you could create a (say) `InitializeName(itemName)` function that you pass the value to, which then stores it in a variable in the external file.